# SQL select records common to a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an `emp` table like this

```
EMPNO | JOB | DEPTNO
_____________________

  1   |  A  |   10

  2   |  B  |   20

  3   |  C  |   10

  4   |  A  |   20
```

I want to write a query to List the jobs common to department 10 and 20.

So the output as per the data provided should be

```
A
```

which is common to both deptno 10 and 20

I am trying this but it doesn't give me any output.

```
select job, deptNo from emp group by job having deptno = 20 and deptno = 10; /*6*/
```

Comment: Change `And` to `Or`.  `Deptno` can't be both at the same time.  Also, just make the `having` a `Where`.

Comment: Why not just `select DISTINCT job, deptNo from emp  where deptno IN (20,10)`?

Comment: I want a job that both deptno 20 and 10 have. So OR won't work, because it will give me jobs that only 20 and only 10 would have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this**

```
    select  job
from    emp e1
where   e1.deptno = 10
and     exists ( select 1
         from   emp e2
         where  e2.deptno = 20
         and    e1.job    = e2.job
    )
group by job;
```

Comment: welcome...and i am happy that...i cud help someone... :)

Comment: can explain me about the exists thing how does it work ?

Comment: 1. e1...we filter dept=10. 2. exists: it is just checking that particular row has any matching criteria in the sub table in the where condition. It is pretty fast as per query plan as well, because exist is powerful than join, etc. basically, in exists, we check if there is any criteria in the sub table matching. if one row matches, the query come, so it is fast. it is little bit tough to explain here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an aggregate function in the `HAVING` clause with the condition you need:

```
SELECT job
FROM emp 
GROUP BY job 
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN deptNo IN (10, 20) THEN 1 END) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The fields can't be both values at the same time.  Use an `Or` instead of `And`.  Also, the `Having` doesn't quite make sense, just use `Where`.

```
select  job, deptNo 
from    emp 
Where   deptno = 20 
Or      deptno = 10
group by job
```

You can also use an `In`, which would have the same effect as an `Or`:

```
select  job, deptNo 
from    emp 
Where   deptno In (10, 20) 
group by job
```

Edit:  You can do this to get the Jobs that have both values:

```
Select  Distinct a.job
From    emp     a
Where   DeptNo = 10
And     Exists 
(
    Select  1
    From    Emp     b
    Where   a.Job = b.Job
    And     b.deptNo = 20
)
```

Comment: So what are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I did - clarify your question?  Maybe put a sample output and sample data?